# Ubuntu 18.04 at boot

Tags: grub2, 18.04

When I boot Ubuntu 18.04 at startup from grub menu, I get stuck on a **black screen**.

I tried changing in `grub.cfg` file, the line `quiet splash` to `nomodeset` and `nomodeset quiet splash`. It seem to have worked when it was loading all the system files but then it got stuck again.

Here are my system specs:

- Asus ROG G551VW
- Intel core i7 6700HQ
- 16 GB RAM
- Nvidia Geforce GTX 960M
- Intel HD Graphics 530

Also fast boot is disabled and so is secure boot.

Sometimes it runs by `nomodeset`, but then again I have no idea how to load intel graphics driver in Ubuntu since I kept on getting 800x600 resolution and no other.

What to do?

Already tried this: [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Now it's not starting with even `nomodeset` when I installed Nvidia drivers.

Comment: Boot with `nomodeset`, disable Secure Boot and install Nvidia driver.

Comment: Yes after I installed nvidia driver, it's not even loading with nomodeset, let alone with quiet splash. What to do now?

Comment: How did you install the driver?

Comment: sudo apt-get install nvidia-375 ??

Comment: Were there any errors? You can always remove it by `sudo apt purge "nvidia.*"`

Comment: None. Message was that it was installed. Then I rebooted, black screen again. Again I opened grub.cfg, changed to nomodeset and then pressed ctrl+X, but this time even this didn't work.

Comment: `nomodeset` is not set in `grub.cfg`. You need to enter it in grub prompt, or permanently add it to `/etc/default/grub`.

Comment: How shall I do that? I am not able to open ubuntu as of now, even in recovery mode. Thanks.

Comment: Follow the instructions in the duplicate.